# Как быстро проверить был ли изменен файл между запусками программы?

Tags: c#, файлы

Сейчас при первом запуске программы я считаю хэш файла, сохраняю его и во время второго запуска просто сравниваю его со вновь посчитанным.

Проблема в том, что это долго. Хотелось бы уметь проверять файл на изменения без подсчёта хэша.

Тут можно было бы запоминать время последнего изменения, но никто не гарантирует, что файл не заменят другим файлом с таким же временем последнего изменения. Такие гарантии можно было бы получить запоминанием [inode](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode), но пока я не могу найти как в C# по имени файла получить [inode](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode). Да и работать это будет не на всех файловых системах.

Как лучше всего решить эту проблему? Как это делает, например, [Dropbox](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox)?

Comment: @Jofsey, inode это из \*nix. Думаю в реализации C# для \*nix есть возможность обратится к системному вызову stat() (или fstat()), а там (в результате вызова) inode  и лежит.

Но, мне кажется, что вероятность изменения содержимого файла без изменения inode и размера такая же, как и изменения файла на новый с тем же размером и временем модификации.

IMHO на практике достаточно смотреть время и размер.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал просто проверить дату последнего изменения.

Объясняю, почему. Если вы хотите выяснить, изменился ли файл обычным образом -- то есть, не редактировал ли его кто-то, проверки даты должно быть достаточно. Это -- правильный, честный способ.

Если же вы хотите переиграть злонамеренного пользователя, то вы уже проиграли: он может сделать что угодно, выставить любую дату изменения, подменить контрольную сумму, которую *ваша программа* где-то хранит, подменить содержимое файла при запросе только от вашей проверяющей процедуры, да что угодно. Не пытайтесь выиграть на чужом поле.

Answer (score 2):

Гарантированный (условно, коллизии неизбежны) результат даст только вычисление хэша. Если у тебя это долго, значит необходимо выбрать более быстрый алгоритм.

Comment: Какой бы быстрый алгоритм вычисления не был выбран, он всё-равно будет упираться в скорость считывания файла с диска. Нужен способ где не нужно читать содержимое файла, или нужно читать лишь небольшой фиксированный размер.

Comment: На счёт гарантий: вероятность того, что у нового файла окажется такой же inode как и у старого достаточно мала чтобы удовлетворить меня.

Comment: Невозможно убедиться в отсутствии изменений, не просмотрев весь файл. Кто-нибудь изменит пару байт содержимого без перезаписи отметки времени изменения этого файла, и никакие inode не помогут.

Comment: >> вероятность того, что у нового файла окажется такой же inode как и у старого достаточно мала чтобы удовлетворить меня

В таком случае, тебе наверняка подойдет WinAPI функция GetFileInformationByHandleEx (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364953(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Предлагаю поставить хук на всевозможные функции системы, которые могут изменить файл. По идее так антивирусы и делают...

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что необходимо оптимизировать максимально чтение файла (например, использовать напрямую функцию Win32API ReadFile) и сделать оптимизированную имплементацию хеш-функции, например, написать ее на ассемблере. Но для начала просто проверять modification time. Если не изменилось, тогда проверять размер файла, если не изменился, считать хеш.